# comparing arima(1,0,0) model to lm produces very similar ar(1) coefficients and very different intercepts

Tags: r, time-series, arima, lm

I'm diving into arima models and was trying to repreduce the results of auto regression.

here is a reproducable example:

```
set.seed(1)
z=arima.sim(n = 101, list(ar = c(0.8)))
```

when running ar(1) without an intercept

```
> ceof(arima(z, order = c(1,0,0),include.mean =FALSE))
ar1 
0.7622461
```

when comparing to a linear regression

```
> coef(lm(z[2:101] ~ z[1:100] + 0))
z[1:100] 
0.7586725
```

which are very similar and can be explained by the different methods used.
However when I do this comparison with models that include an intercept, I get again similar results in the ar1 coefficient but very different measures for the intercept. while the intercept that I get in the arima model is the one that makes less sense to me.

```
> coef(arima(z, order = c(1,0,0)))
      ar1 intercept 
0.7274511 0.4241322 
> coef(lm(z[2:101] ~ z[1:100]))
(Intercept)    z[1:100] 
  0.1578015   0.7130261
```

Any ideas on these differencing and in what way the arima procedure is different?

Answer (score 3):

The thing that's called an "intercept" in the output of the `arima` function in R, isn't -- not what you'd normally think of as an intercept, anyway. It's actually the estimate of the $\mu$ parameter:

\begin{eqnarray}
(y_t-\mu) &=& \phi_1(y_{t-1}-\mu)+\varepsilon_t\\
&=&\mu + \phi_1 y_{t-1}-\phi_1\mu+\varepsilon_t\\
&=&\mu(1-\phi_1) + \phi_1 y_{t-1}+\varepsilon_t\\
&=&\phi_0 + \phi_1 y_{t-1}+\varepsilon_t
\end{eqnarray}

If you calculate $\phi_0=\mu(1-\phi_1)$ for the ARIMA model, it's much closer to that of the conditional least squares model:

```
 0.4241322 *(1-0.7274511)
[1] 0.1155968
```

As for why the (now equivalent) coefficients are similar but different, that's essentially down to the `arima` function including the likelihood for the first observation, which your `lm` fit conditions on.

Answer (score 0):

I could actually close the question but maybe it would be useful to others:

found the answer in [this site](http://www.stat.pitt.edu/stoffer/tsa2/Rissues.htm)

after following the link from [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27893735/arima-fails-to-estimate-a-simple-ar1-in-r)

Comment: link-only answers are not preferred ... can you edit the question to include essential information from the linked site?